# traverse through elements returned by getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm finding all elements for a class name with getElementsByClassName like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
```

and I want to travers all elements including children of children, all elements.

what I'm doing now is this:

```
for(var i=0; i< elements.length; i++) elements[i].children[0];
```

but this is not good because it will not traverse all elements including children of children. And I don't know the parent children tree.

How traverse all elements of parent element including children of children.

Comment: If you're familiar with recursion, this seems like a pretty good place for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generic way :

```
var recursive = function (element) {
// some stuff with element
console.log(element);
// check if children
var children = element.children;
if (children) {
    for(var i=0; i< children.length; i++) { 
        // apply recursion on each child
        recursive(children[i]);
    }
}
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('postcell');

for(var i=0; i< elements.length; i++) { 
 recursive(elements[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`element.getElementsByTagName('*')` will give give you all the descendant elements of an element.

Alternatively, you can use `children` recursively.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this:**

```
var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
var eleMyClass = new Array();
var j=0;
for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    if(elements[i].className=="myclass"){
    eleMyClass[j]=elements[i];
    j++;
    }
}
```

Now the Array **`eleMyClass`** contains the list of the elements with class Name `myclass`

Answer (score 0):

Using `getElementsByTagName('*')` you can arrange your code like this so you have a nested loop and a variable `elm` inside it which points at the current node to let you do work on it.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass'),
    i, j, nodes, elm;

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements[i].getElementsByTagName('*'));
    nodes.unshift(elements[i]);
    for (j = 0; j < nodes.length; ++j) {
        elm = nodes[j];
        // work with elm
    }
}
```

If you wanted to just `return` an *Array* of all the *Elements*, you could `concat` the *Array* I called `nodes` instead of the second `for`